# Deployed ASP MVC5 site to Azure, getting 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, web-hosting

I built a ASP.NET MVC5 website locally using a local database. I got it to a point I wanted to bring it up onto azure web services, so I enabled an Azure website and set to deploy from the Visual Studio Online Git repo. The deployments take place but accessing the page only generates an 'An error occurred while processing your request.' error.

If I look into the logs I get the following error listed:

> 1. MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
>
> Warning   ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler",
>   Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="500",
>   HttpReason="Internal Server Error", HttpSubStatus="0", ErrorCode="The
>   operation completed successfully.  (0x0)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""

The connection string for the database had been replaced with an AzureSqlDatabase connection string so I tried checking there. The string 'looks' fine, but I noticed that when I run the application in Debug mode it is somehow using the original local Sql Database despite that connection string no longer being in the code!

I've tried some of the suggestions listed in SO, including enabling detailed logging and re-pushing the web.config file, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas on how I can track down and resolve this issue?

EDIT:
With MFanto's help I found that the application is still somehow using the old local SQL Databases's connection string. (Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HouseOfBurt.Models.DataContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True)

The Web.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Application" />
        <add namespace="Application.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*"
           preCondition="integratedMode"
           type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The Web.Debug.Config (password modified of course)

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--
    In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of
    "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator
    finds an attribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB"
        connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  -->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name ="DataContextContainer" connectionString="Server=tcp:r0c0umg8th.database.windows.net,1433;Database=HouseOfBurt;User ID=dba@r0c0cmg8th;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    <!--
      In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire
      <customErrors> section of your Web.config file.
      Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the
      <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
    -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

EDIT2: Addition of the DbContext class:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        #region Tables

        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Link> Links { get; set; }

        #endregion Tables

        #region Public Methods

        #endregion Public Methods

    }
```

Comment: How is the connection string being replaced? By the Azure website settings on the portal, or with web.config transforms (e.g. web.debug.config and web.release.config)? Have you tried remote debugging the azure site to see where it's breaking?

Comment: I had changed the actual web.Config. I'll see if I can do a remote session.

Comment: Having trouble getting the debug session to attach, but it did report a SqlException. The web.config, web.debug.config and web.release.config all have the same connection string pointing to the Entity framework. Despite that the local debugging still connects to the local SQL instance so I'm doing something wrong. Any idea what?

Comment: Can you post your web.config file? Also your DbContext

Comment: Remote debugging results in a error message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: let's get this straight.  You have added the same connection string in all 3 .config files, but when testing locally, it's using a different database (localdb, presumably), and when uploading to Azure it's trying to use that db and failing, yes?  Can you share your DBContext class for Entity Framework?

Comment: @Andrew, yes. Its clearly using the original SqlExpress connection string in both cases, even though a solution-wide search reveals no instances of it in the solution.

Comment: your `DbContext` Class you posted is named `DataContext` but the connection string in your example is `DataContextContainer`.  If a connection string is not explicitly supplied, Entity Framework will look for a Connection String which name matches **exactly** to the name of the DBContext; else convention will attempt to use a code based connection string, targeting SQLExpress.  Try changing the connection string name and see if it has any effect.

Comment: for more context on this convention see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `DbContext` Class you posted is named `DataContext` but the connection string in your example is `DataContextContainer`.

If a connection string is not explicitly supplied, Entity Framework will look for a Connection String which name matches **exactly** to the name of the DBContext; else convention will attempt to use a code based connection string, targeting SQLExpress.

Changing the connection string name seems to have fixed the issue.

More information on the conventions relating to Entity Framework Connection Strings can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.